# Replacing damaged 2012 domain controller with Win 2019

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain-controller, upgrade, windows-server-2019

We have a domain with 2 DC's, both Win 2012.  The local DC works fine, but the remote DC has a growing list of problems due to frequent power outages (and improper shutdown).  I would like to take this opportunity to upgrade the domain to Win 2019.

Reviewing MS's instructions online, MS says that both DC's must be working properly, and dcdiag /v must pass.  However, replication between DC's fails and after hours of tinkering I give up.  I accept that I won't make dcdiag happy.

Is it safe to just demote the remote DC, so replication testing isn't an issue?  and then upgrade normally as a single DC domain?  (Will removing the remote DC prevent any replication test failures)?  I can always add the remote DC afterwards.

Then what is the best way to upgrade my domain?  For example

1. Demote old remote DC
2. Add a new local win2019 DC
3. Transfer old-to-new local DC roles
4. Demote old local DC
5. Add new remote win2019 DC

Any danger in my approach?  I'm nervous about DCDIAG failing before I even start